# Exception when undoing deletion of managed objects: "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts"

Tags: exception, core-data, undo

I have received some reports from customers with this exception:

```
'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'titleBox' between objects in different contexts
0   CoreFoundation                      0x96a856ca __raiseError + 410
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x921535a9 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x96ad0a21 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   ExceptionHandling                   0x998d44c5 -[NSExceptionHandler _handleException:mask:] + 1877
4   ExceptionHandling                   0x998d3d52 NSExceptionHandlerExceptionRaiser + 228
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x921535a9 objc_exception_throw + 56
6   CoreData                            0x92da3278 _PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 1768
7   CoreData                            0x92db9e8f _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 159
8   CoreData                            0x92da2a56 -[NSManagedObject(_PFDynamicAccessorsAndPropertySupport) _setGenericValue:forKey:withIndex:flags:] + 54
9   CoreData                            0x92dbd689 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 505
10  CoreData                            0x92dbd321 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 961
11  CoreData                            0x92dbcf4b -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 187
12  Foundation                          0x95d4502c NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 372
13  Foundation                          0x95d44acb NSKeyValueDidChange + 377
14  Foundation                          0x95d292b6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 127
15  CoreData                            0x92dbce25 -[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 69
16  Sandvox                             0x0006ecc6 -[KSExtensibleManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 858
17  CoreData                            0x92de9deb -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _updateFromToManyAwareSnapshot:forUndo:] + 683
18  CoreData                            0x92de6540 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _updateFromUndoSnapshot:] + 48
19  CoreData                            0x92de5775 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _undoDeletions:] + 1093
20  Foundation                          0x95eadb60 -[_NSUndoLightInvocation invoke] + 34
21  Foundation                          0x95eadf60 -[_NSUndoStack popAndInvoke] + 265
22  Foundation                          0x95eae2a0 -[NSUndoManager undoNestedGroup] + 342
```

We've not been able to reproduce it so far. It looks to me like Core Data is attempting to connect up one object which has been "un-deleted" with another that is yet to receive the same treatment. Why on earth would Core Data do this to itself?

Comment: Is it possible that you actually do have more than one managed object context, like the error message says?

Comment: Well I do have one MOC per document, but that can't be a factor here. There's no way I can imagine the contexts becoming intertwined, especially by Core Data's own undo manager. Plus vast majority of our customers only have a single document